# Built-in RAM disk solution for Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, performance, ramdisk

I remember that back in the "good old days" of MSDOS a RAM disk driver was bundled with the "OS" and by doing some simple settings it was possible to configure it.

Does Microsoft still supply this for Windows (XP,2000,2003)?

The only reference I can find is to commercial software such as http://www.ramdisk.tk

In the corporate environment, the overhead of approval and ordering the software and requesting installation is huge compared to configuration of the OS or something free from Microsoft. So I am looking for an OS or Microsoft solution in preference to a commerical one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One is provided with Windows XP, but it's a bit tricky to find:

- In Control Panel, go to **Add Hardware**
- Click next
- Select **Yes, I have already connected the hardware** and click next
- Scroll down to the very bottom and select **Add a new hardware device** then click next
- Select **Install the hardware that I manually select from a list** then click next
- Select **Show all devices** then click next
- Scroll down the **Manufacturer** list and select **Microsoft**, not **Microsoft Corporation**
- Scroll down the **Model** list and you'll see **Microsoft Ram Disk Controller**:

[image]

Comment: Except that has no visible effect. It would be good if the answer demonstrated how to configure and use it.

Comment: @Synetech tell me you did not look at the next line in that list without telling me you did not look at the next line on that list

Answer (score 1):

As a second suggestion (in case the built-in do not fit your needs): *ImDisk*

(the Web site have a "years 80's old fashion" look but the software works well...)

[ImDisk Web site](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk)